# Capture sound card line out in C++

Tags: visual-c++, delphi-7, c++builder

I try to learn how to record sound from PC devices. I found an example which shows how to record sound from mic. But cannot find example how to record from sound card line out.
Please if you can help me, show me example, or give me good links, because I searched a lot and didnt found that. I'm working with Visual C++ , C++ Builder, Delphi.  Thanks.

Comment: @AngeDeLaMort Yes, any example is good. I need to record all sound which sound card play, means sound which go to speaker. I do not need to record microphone, only sound which you hear in speakers.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you mean: you want to record any sound that your computer play? I never did that, but maybe a library like that can help you http://www.portaudio.com/ or look at msdn waveOut Api http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743866%28v=vs.85%29.aspx . If that's what you are looking for, I'll make a proper answer out of it.

Comment: I think loppback recording is what you're looking for.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316551(v=vs.85).aspx